# When scanning Wi-Fi networks with Android's WifiManager, how do I avoid seeing cached networks?

Tags: android

I use `WifiManager.startScan` for scanning available networks. It works fine and I can work with returned networks. But there is one problem. Sometimes(unexpectly? when wifi starts?) it returns networks which is not available. This network was available but is far away now. It looks like wifimanager have some networks cached.

Is there some solution? I have only one - scan networks twice but it's not ideal. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1):

Each **[`ScanResult`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/ScanResult.html)** entry that you get back has a **[`level`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/ScanResult.html#level)** field, which indicates the signal strength in dBm units. The lower this value, the weaker the signal. You can exclude networks below a certain signal strength to avoid seeing networks that might not accept a connection.

Comment: The problem is that if network is not available - is only cached, it has cached also level.